# Invoking a method in all class's objects simultaneously in java

Tags: java

I have a problem in java programming , how can i make all objects of a class invoke a method of themselves simultaneously in java ?

thank in advance.

Comment: maybe you are thinking on static methods...which belong to the class not to the instance

Comment: Do all of a class's instances invoke a method, if I declare the method static and invoke the class's method ?

Comment: *"I have a problem.."* ..in explaining the problem. --  What exactly are to trying to achieve?  Explain it to me as though I were a potential user, tying to decide whether to buy *your* software, or that of your *competitor*.

Comment: I have a class Flip and this class has a method calculate(). there are many instance of this class. I need that all of the instances invokes their calculate methods simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, why don't you keep all instances of the class in a collection and then iterate over them and invoke the method you wish on all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for what I understood of your question:

```
public class Flip {

    private static List<Flip> instances = new ArrayList<Flip>();

    [... fields, etc]

    public Flip() {
         [...init the fields]
         synchronized(instances) {
             // if you access the instances list, you have to protect it
             instances.add(this); // save this instance to the list
         }
    }

    [... methods]

    public void calculate() {
        synchronized(instances) {
            // if you access the instances list, you have to protect it
            for (Flip flip : instances) {
                // call the doCalculate() for each Flip instance
                flip.doCalculate();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doCalculate() {
       [... here comes the original calculation logic]
    }
}
```

The key point is that you have to register all instances of Flip somehow. Later on you can iterate them through.

Comment: dear richcoleuk thanks for your interest. Indeed i want to simulate the behavior of the D Flip-Flops. As you know in logic design, when the edge of clock pulse arrives the input of all the D flip-flops are transferred to their outputs simultaneously. Iterating a list is not suitable solution because it has a sequential approach not a concurrent. So i need a way that all of flip-flops instances invoke a method simultaneously. Regards.

Comment: Maybe you wrote this comment to the wrong answer. Also, I think that my answer was much more complete and detailed than that.